# Display dynamic content based on current user ID in Joomla

Tags: php, sql, join, joomla

I am developing a custom module that displays a dynamic list of articles based on whether the current user has read an article or not. When a user reads or 'submits' an article, the article id and title is stored in a table called "completed_quests." The dynamic list will only display articles that are NOT found in the completed_quests table. The code below is completely functional, however I am running into a bit of an issue.

Currently, the list is being displayed in the same way regardless of which user is logged in. For instance, let's say that user 540 reads and submits an article. When user 541 logs in - it is displaying the list as if user 541 has submitted the quest as well. I may be over complicating this, but I need to get the list to display in a unique way depending on which user is logged in. Please see the code below. I have already pulled the user ID from the database and defined the $userID variable. Now I just need to know where it fits in to the equation.

Edit: Below is the revised, working code.

```
<?php

$catID = JRequest::getVar('id');
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userID = (int)$user->id;

$query = "SELECT * FROM arp2i_completed_quests AS r
RIGHT JOIN arp2i_content AS c
ON c.id=r.id 
AND c.catid=r.catid 
AND r.user_id = $userID
WHERE r.user_id IS NULL "; // prepare query

$db = &JFactory::getDBO(); // get database object
$db->setQuery($query); // apply query
$articles = $db->loadObjectList(); // execute query, return result list

foreach($articles as $article){ // loop through articles

if ($article->id >1 && $article->catid == $catID) {
       echo '<a href="http://localhost/quest/index.php/quests/' . $article->id . '-' . $article->title . '">' . 'ID:' . $article->id . ' Title: ' . $article->title . '</a>' . '<br />';}
} 

?>
```

Comment: What is the db structure of the completed_quests table as I don't see the where condition to the user ID.

Comment: completed_quests contains user_id, id, title, catid.

Comment: I have a unique index on user_id and id to avoid creating duplicate rows, if that helps.

Comment: You have to remove that index or span it over the columns user_id, id, catid. otherwise it is only allowed to create one record per user, but have probably more than one article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your answer is the id field in the arp2i_completed_quests the article id. Then you have to swap the join and make a condition with the user id.

```
<?php
$catID = JRequest::getVar('id');
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userID = (int)$user->id;

$query = "SELECT * FROM arp2i_content as c ";
$query .= "left JOIN arp2i_completed_quests as r on ";
$query .= "c.id=r.id AND c.catid=r.catid and r.user_id != ".$userID." ";
$query .= "where r.id is null"; // prepare query

$db = JFactory::getDBO(); // get database object
$db->setQuery($query); // apply query
$articles = $db->loadObjectList(); // execute query, return result list

foreach ($articles as $article) { // loop through articles
    if ($article->id > 1 and $article->catid == $catID) {
        echo '<a href="http://localhost/quest/index.php/quests/' . $article->id . '-' . $article->title . '">' . 'ID:' .
             $article->id . ' Title: ' . $article->title . '</a>' . '<br />';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: First of all...you just blew my mind with the "arp2i_content as c" stuff. That saves so much time coding since you don't have to write out the whole table name throughout the entire query. THANK YOU. Second, your answer just got me most of the way to a solution, although I needed to swap it from a left to a right join and now it does exactly what I need. I will update the code to what I have now.

Comment: But you really should be using the api.  Why wouldn't you be useing baseUrl()?  Don't hard code in things like your domain or your prefix--there's a reason all that is stored in the configuration object.

Comment: @Elin, I totally agree with you, just wanted to give him a starting point.